# Equivalent in vb.net's MaskedTextBox to cliptext property in vb6's Masked Edit control

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration, maskedtextbox

I find this property useful but cannot find a direct replacement for it in vb.net. Is there one? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals` before you get the text from the `Text` property.